# iText - Image side bar

Tags: java, image, itext, qr-code

I am generating a QRCode usign iText library. And then putting it into PDF file. Problem is that image is generated with "side bars".

I've tried lots of functions of Image class but it is not working. 
I am attaching the screen shot as well snippet also.

Image is like this:

(not border - but white bar without border) -----------------------

```
                   BlankSpace --> between above line and below line 

              Border of my image____________________________
```

And the snippet is :

```
System.out.println("Putting a QR...");
BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode(data, 100, 100, null);
com.itextpdf.text.Image img = qrcode.getImage();
                img.setBorder(0);
                img.setBorderWidth(0.0f);
                img.scaleAbsolute(img.getHeight()*0.48f, img.getWidth()*0.48f);
                //img.scalePercent(50, 50);
                //img.scaleToFit(50, 50);
                            img.setAbsolutePosition(7, 15);
                img.setAlignment(Image.TEXTWRAP);
                over.addImage(img);
                over.closePath();

                System.out.println(img.getBorderWidth());
                System.out.println(img.getBorderWidthLeft());
                //System.out.println(img.type());
                System.out.println(img.getHeight());
                System.out.println(img.getPlainHeight());
                System.out.println(img.getScaledHeight());
```

Comment: you found any solution?